# Batch Convert .mp4 to .avi with ffmpeg

Tags: conversion, ffmpeg

Running Ubuntu 13.10 with a fully compiled `ffmpeg`. I know the code for the actual conversion is `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -codec copy video.avi`

I just need a plain and simple Bash script to do that for, say, forty or fifty of the `.mp4` files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a list of file you can use something like:

```
cat list-of-files.txt | while read file; do ffmpeg -i $file -codec copy ${file%%.mp4}.avi; done
```

or simply

```
cd /path/; ls *.mp4 | while read file; do ffmpeg -i $file -codec copy ${file%%.mp4}.avi; done
```

Comment: you can avoid `cat` using `while ..do..done < list-of-files.txt`

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in *.avi; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -codec copy "`echo $i | sed 's/.avi$/.mp4/'`"; done
```